# function only reading one row of data

Tags: python

im doing a csi python  project. my string function wont read all the data in my file. only one row is appearing,

I've searched across this website. went online to different sites, and gotten help from peers.

...

```
python
def readData():
    weatherlist = []
    file = open("KMDW.csv","r")
    sheet = file.readline()
    for x in file:
        innerlist = []
        x = x.split(",")
        for y in file:
           innerlist.append(y)
        weatherlist.append(innerlist)
    print(x)
    return x
readData()
```

...

I want the function to read all the rows of data. However,I am only getting one row of data shown after returning the list.

Comment: Have you tried using `file.readlines()` instead of `file.readline()`? I think that's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I'm guessing that you meant to read the first line separately as a header line.  Then you want to use `file.readlines()` to process the rest of the lines. `readlines()` will give you lines with EOL characters at the end, so you should do a `strip()` on each line to not end up with a CR in your last element.  Your inner loop doesn't seem to be doing anything for you, and it never makes sense to iterate over an object a second time inside the first iteration.  Given that, and that you probably want to be returning the `weatherlist` list you're building up, here's what I think you want:

```
def readData():
    weatherlist = []
    file = open("KMDW.csv","r")
    sheet = file.readline()
    for x in file.readlines():
        x = x.strip().split(",")
        weatherlist.append(x)
    return weatherlist

weatherlist = readData()
print(weatherlist)
```

If the first line of your file is a data line like all the others, just take out the line `sheet = file.readline()`.

In the future, I'd suggest that you post your data, as it's hard to know just what you're trying to do without it.  Including just the first 3-4 lines is often sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Is this works?

```
def readData():
    weatherlist = []
    file = open("KMDW.csv","r")
    sheet = file.readlines()
    for x in sheet:
        innerlist = []
        x = x.split(",")
        for y in x:
           innerlist.append(y)
        weatherlist.append(innerlist)
    print(weatherlist)
    return weatherlist
readData()
```

Comment: I think there are bunch of errors so I fixed some variables.

Answer (score 0):

`file.readline()` will only read a single line at a time. Replace that with `file.readlines()` to read all the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `file` is a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/). This mean that you exhaust the content of the file as you read through it.
i.e. you cannot loop twice over the variable file you would have to open it again.

When you loop like below you will exhaust the whole file generator. Hence on the second iteration of `for x in file` there is nothing to iterate through and results in reading only one row.

```py
for y in file:
    innerlist.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `readData` function you are returning x, which at the end of loop will have the last row value. Ideally, you should use `return weatherList` for returning all rows.

```
def readData():
    weatherlist = []
    file = open("KMDW.csv","r")
    sheet = file.readline()
    for x in file:
        innerlist = []
        x = x.split(",")
        for y in file:
           innerlist.append(y)
        weatherlist.append(innerlist)
    print(x)
    return weatherList
readData()
```